# When we draw a column of text, how to increase the spacing of the text

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

```
p2 <- df |> mutate(x="col1") |> 
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=fct_rev(id)))+
  geom_text(aes(label=1:72),hjust=align,size=3)+
  geom_stripped_rows()+
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(rep(0,4),"cm")
  )+
  labs(x="cancer_type")+
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top")
p2
```

I have draw a column of text include 1:72, but I think  the  space between each row is too small to see the word clearly. i wonder how can i increase the spacing of the text

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06oE4.png)

I have tried "lineheight" in geom_text, but it does not work

```
p2 <- df |> mutate(x="col1") |> 
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=fct_rev(id)))+
  geom_text(aes(label=1:72),hjust=align,size=3,lineheight = 10)+
  geom_stripped_rows()+
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(rep(0,4),"cm")
  )+
  labs(x="cancer_type")+
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top")
p2
```

Comment: The column fills the entire plotting panel. Logically, it is impossible to increase the spacing between the numbers without either making the text smaller or the plot larger, so those are your two basic options.

Comment: ...so if you're working with an interactive graphics window, adjust the window size to be bigger. If you're saving a file, increase the height dimension. Or make the `size` of the text smaller.

Comment: think you for your advise! i  smaller the size and increase the height when release the image as PDF.  well  , i think it looks better now